# Trouble inserting text value into HTML input with TWebBrowser.EvaluateJavaScript()

Tags: javascript, android, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I use `TWebBrowser` to insert data into a web form. My application is written in Delphi FMX and runs on Android. The element type `text` is not inserting the value string.

HTML:

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="txtCPF" 
  id="txtCPF" 
  size="18" 
  maxlength="14" 
  autofocus="" 
  title="Informe os onze dígitos do número do CPF." 
  onkeypress="javascript: return EntradaNumerico(event);" 
  onfocus="javascript: RemoveMask('txtCPF');" 
  onblur="javascript: FG_FormatarCPF('txtCPF');" 
  autocomplete="off" 
  value=""
>
```

I need to insert into element `txtCPF` the value type String `'02403989987'`, but

- if use this code:

  ```pascal
  var
    wbConsultaCPF: TWebBrowser;
  begin
    wbConsultaCPF.EvaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtCPF").value = "012345";');
  ```

  ...the browser shows just

  > 012345

  in white screen. In an iOS application, the code works correctly.
- If I use:

  ```pascal
    wbConsultaCPF.EvaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtCPF").value = 012345;');
  ```

  ...the browser shows the correct text in the element value, but cuts off the first zero:

  > 12345

```pascal
wbConsultaCPF.URL := 'https://servicos.receita.fazenda.gov.br/servicos/cpf/consultasituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp';
```

Comment: `value = "012345"` assigns a string literal, whereas `value = 012345` assigns an integer literal.  In an integer, a leading `0` is not part of the actual numeric value, which is why the text shows as `12345` instead of `012345`. I'm not seeing a problem here, this is working as expected.

Comment: The problem is: if use wbConsultaCPF.EvaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById("txtCPF").value = "012345";'); with quotes does not work. Show white screen with string 012345 and need fill string in the form element. I can't set a string value in a form element through the function '.evaluateJavaScript()' in TWebBrowser.

Comment: "*does not work. Show white screen*" - Please [edit] your question to provide screenshots of what you are actually seeing.

Comment: And what happens when using apostrophs? `('document.getElementById(''txtCPF'').value= ''012345'';');`

Comment: @AmigoJack that shouldn't make any difference to Javascript

Comment: The following JavaScript works for me in TWebBrowser on Android: `(function() { document.getElementById("txtCPF").value = "012345"; })()`

Comment: Also for anyone else following: the original code causes a white screen for me on Android i.e. the browser area is completely white, except for the value. The original code works on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function in .EvaluateJavaScript() and it worked.
Example:

wbConsultaCPF.EvaluateJavaScript('(function() { document.getElementById("txtCPF").value = "012345"; })()');